# kubernetes how to collect log file without stdout or stderr

Tags: kubernetes

My pod have more than one log file, such as `php-fpm` + `nginx` stack. How to collect the log files?

I know nginx doing it with symlink. But this cannot deal with more than 2 log files.

I want to mount volume in host to pods, but how to set different folder for every pod? Is there anyway to mount a folder named by `podname` in the host to pod folder `/logs`.

[raychaser](https://github.com/raychaser/powerstrip-logfiles) gave a way to collect folders to `/var/log/containers/`, but I don't think it works in kubernetes.

Comment: What does this have to do with stdout / stderr? It's the top result for "kubernetes stdout" yet has nothing to do with it that I can tell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I find a way to collect the logs.

1. Make sure all apps write all log files to a folder, e.g.
   `/med/log`.
2. Make sure all apps start the job with a script, e.g.
   `entrypoint.sh`.
3. Create a folder named by $HOSTNAME in mount volume, e.g.
   `/log/$HOSTNAME`
4. Link the folder: `ln -sf /log/$HOSTNAME /med/log`.

In k8s, you need to mount the host log folder `/var/log/k8s/` to `/log`. And the log dir looks like:

```
/var/log/k8s/
|-- app1-${container_id}/
|   |-- access.log
|   |-- error.log
|-- app2-${container_id}/
    |-- access.log
    |-- error.log
```

Comment: This is great, however introduces a risk of consuming the whole /var/ disk and causing other pods or services to fail. There was a PR proposal to create a logDir in upcoming k8s, which enabled resource restrictions.

Comment: You can also try to leverage `--log-dir=XXX`.

Comment: Thanks, Subodh, do you mean `kubectl --logtostderr=false --log-dir=/med/log`? And can you explain the "PR proposal to create a logDir in upcoming k8s" clearly?

Comment: Yes, thats the intended way of using. That proposal was implemented to be the same. Thanks Chao.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a logging solution like Fluentd, which allows you to define multiple information sources. As you have several log files it could work for your use case.

http://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/quickstart
http://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/config-file

Comment: But fluentd only collect host files, such as `/var/lib/docker/containers/*` and `/var/log/container/*`, cannot collect the file in container, unless you mount the log to the host. But how can we make sure every container mount to different folder in the host?