# Kubernetes: how can I mount container log files to host

Tags: logging, kubernetes, docker-volume

I've an applicaion running inside pod which is created by deployment specification in k8s. As I've NFS clients in all nodes, I can mount volume from host to pod. Here is the mount-vol portion of yml file

```
spec:
  containers:
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /app/config
      name: config-volume
    - mountPath: /var/log
      name: logs

  volumes:
  - name: config-volume
    hostPath:
      path: /nfs/config
  - name: logs
    hostPath:
      path: /nfs/logs/containerlogs
```

**config-volume**: it mounts the config files from host to pod container.

**logs**: it is **not working**. I want to mount the log folder from pod container to host folder.

Comment: There are a couple of suggestions on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44215229/kubernetes-how-to-collect-log-file-without-stdout-or-stderr - do they help?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you mount containers to host. It is always host to pod.  Make sure that the path /nfs/logs/containerLogs exist in the host so that your pod can write to it.

Comment: /nfs/logs/containerlogs exists but can not write logs

Comment: there's no error. when I mount container file to host file then logs cannot write

Comment: When you say logs cannot write usually you get some message why it cannot write.

Answer (score -1):

As for me, your yaml almost do work.
Personally, I think your yaml need to be completed, such as:

```
spec:
  containers:
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /app/config
      name: config-volume
    - mountPath: /var/log
      name: logs

  volumes:
  - name: config-volume
    hostPath:
      path: /nfs/config
      type: Directory
  - name: logs
    hostPath:
      path: /nfs/logs/containerlogs
      type: Directory
```

Also your spec missed configs `image` & `command`

As you described above, there are 2 paths to store 2 kinds of logs.

What you may also do is to assign the 2 paths in your container spec, just like the way you start your application without container.

Actually, the similar configure in your spec is as follows:

```
              command:
              - /application
              - --log-dir=/var/log
              - --config-log-dir=/app/config
              - --logtostderr=false
              - --v=3
```

You may noticed that the arguments `- --logtostderr` and `- --v=3`. If your application has similar arguments, you should set them properly.

After you do the right config, the container will logs the log to the right place.